# How to arrange items into sections in a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, dynamic, tableview

**Easiest way I can say this is how would I be able to arrange the cells into sections by their brand inside the CartVC**

**Since all Im trying to do is organize the cells by their brand in the Cart** similar to how the contacts are arranged in our phones work once data is passed into the cart from the HomeVC

The code does pass data from the HomeVC to the CartVC successfully, But the cells still do not arrange by their brand name

[image]

```
extension HomeController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemSetup.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell") as? HomeCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        let item = itemSetup[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(withItems: item)

        // passes data to the Cart CartVC when ATC Btn is pressed in each cell
        cell.addActionHandler = { (option: Int) in
            print("Option selected = \(option)")
            Tray.currentCart.cartItems.append(item)
            item.selectedOption = option
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class CartViewController: UIViewController {

    var items: Items!

    var setUp: [Items] = []
    var groupedItems: [String: [Items]] = [:]
    var brands: [String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var cartTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        cartTableView.dataSource = self
        cartTableView.delegate = self

        groupedItems = Dictionary(grouping: setUp, by: {$0.brand})
        brands = groupedItems.map{$0.key}.sorted()
    }

}

extension CartViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Tray.currentCart.cartItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCell", for: indexPath) as! CartCell


        let brand = brands[indexPath.section]
        let itemToDisplay = groupedItems[brand]![indexPath.row]

        // code that currently transfers data to the cells when ATC is pressed
        let cart = Tray.currentCart.cartItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(withItems: cart)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cartHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartHeaderCell") as! CartHeaderCell

        let headerTitle = brands[section]

        return cartHeader
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 45
     } 
}
```

Comment: Few people spend more than a minute reading somebody else's question.  So you may want to shorten your question.

Comment: you're right, will do

Comment: Can you please write what exact issue in a line?

Comment: my issue is how would I be able to arrange the cells into sections by their brand inside the CartVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't follow all your code on here, but assuming you have an array `items` which is an array of `Item` where each `item` has a `.brand: String` property

on entering view controller, set up your data to display:

```
var items: [Item] //populated in segue
var groupedItems: [String: [Items]] =[:]
var brands: [String] = []

override viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // any other stuff
  groupedItems = Dictionary(grouping: items, by: {$0.brand})
  brands = groupedItems.map{$0.key}.sorted()
}
```

use the `brands` array to form your custom headers and then in `cellForRowAt` retrieve the item you need to display based on the indexPath parameter

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {    
  return brands.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let brand = brands[section]
    return groupedItems[brand].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
   let headerTitle = brands[section]
   // create and configure the header view
   // the headerTitle contains the 'brand' string for the header
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestCartCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCartCell

   // retrieve the relevant item to display...
   // 1. use the section to retrieve the specific brand name string for the section from the brands array
   // 2. then use that that to retrieve the appropriate items array from the dictionary
   // 3. the use indexPath.row to retrieve the specific item for the cell

   let brand = brands[indexPath.section]
   let itemToDisplay = grouped[brand]![indexPath.row]

   //configure cell with itemToDisplay...

   return cell
}
```

Comment: Would I put this in my HomeVC or my CartVC? and how would I set it up to place my brands in the header?, sorryc @flanker for the late response I just got off work and im all ears now

Comment: Would the TrayDataSource, the TrayItem class and its extension be needed? or would I just eliminate them altogether? **Since all Im trying to do is organize the cells by their brand in the Cart similar to how the contacts are arranged in our phones work** once data is passed into the cart from the HomeVC

Comment: @Evelyn no worries about the timing.  This goes into the CartVC, and is geared around displaying the card conents grouped by their `.brand` property.  I'll have to check what those other items are being used for

Comment: If all those classes are being used for is to get the items grouped by brand ready for then tableView then they can be removed. You'll have to change the other tableview functions to use the `brands` array for section headers, and the `groupedItems` dictionary for cell info.  But it should all work out a lot simpler than before.

Comment: the only class that I would really need to make this work in my Cart is the Tray class then. The other two **(TrayItem and TrayDataSource)** are what I was using to to make it it organize for testing purposes. I'll update my question more accordingly so it looks cleaner

Comment: I just integrated your code into the Question still a little confused at what steps what I would take from here to arrange cells and place the brands in their own custom header

Comment: I've added another level of detail to the answer to help you implement this approach. (typed on mobile, so you might have to fix minor typos!)

Comment: I just tested it and it didn't work it failed to pass data to the cart when I pressed the ATCbtn in the Cart Cell I just added the code to my question but I fell like some of the code that have cannot be removed like ```cell.configure(withItems: cart)``` since it is what allows the function to be able to be passed into the cells of the cart. I just updated my question with some of the code from your answer

Comment: The example code supplied was just for how to display your data in the tableView, as per the original question.  You still need to integrate it into your app workflow and make sure the data is in the correct place.  I suggest you go and try and get it working, and post another question if you hit a specific problem, as this one is becoming too rambling and off the original topic.

Comment: I feel like were so close to the solution @flanker, I doing everything I can to make this work, maybe this is going a little off but its in lines with what im trying to do. im really doing my best this make this work Flanker

Comment: You are, so keep trying - you'll learn far more by working it out yourself than copying/pasting answers from here.  If there is specific bits you get stuck on, post focussed question on the problems and you'll get help.

Comment: modified my code and got rid of the currentCart from the Tray class it works now

Answer (score 0):

It could be simply implemented by

1. Create a list all unique brands for all your products in cart(products array) : Create a `<SET>` and iterate through all the products selected and add their brand in `<SET>`
2. For every brand in `<SET>` , create a predicate that filters out all products of the brand, you can also user `Filter` for it. Store the results in separate brand array and once processing is done , set the number of columns in TableView to number of arrays created after filtering , and number of rows in each section to count of each array

Hope this helps !

Comment: im a little confused in how to do this, can you be more specific?